# webpack4 webpack-dev-server ssl in config file

Tags: ssl, webpack, https, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Following [this cli command](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/cli/https):

```
npm run webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --cert=../../ssl/server.pem --key=../../ssl/server.pem
```

I would like to add the files in my webpack.config file.. something like:

```
module.exports = {

    ...

    ssl: {
        cred: "../../ssl/server.pem", 
        key: "../../ssl/server.pem"
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was open in my browser for an hour while I was trying to solve it... and eventually I did.. so hopefully I can save someone else and hour :)

[link to reference](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-https)

```
module.exports = {

    ...
    devServer: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server.crt'),
            ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.pem'),
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Maybe 3 hours.. if you need to generate your own certificate.. and Chrome just breaks..

[To generate your dev certificate](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/854#issuecomment-292445914):

```
openssl req \
    -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -x509 \
    -nodes \
    -keyout server.pem \
    -new \
    -out server.pem \
    -subj /CN=localhost \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -extensions SAN \
    -config <(cat /System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf \
        <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost')) \
    -sha256 \
    -days 3650
```

Comment: Actually you can remove "ca" property, "key" and "cert" is also enough for bare minimum.