# Is there a way to completely reset a docker-compose service ? ('cause I am unable to use npm anymore)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, api-platform.com

I am using Symfony ApiPlatform 2.5 on Docker, with a "client" service for ReactJs frontend. I don't really know what happened, but I can't do anything more with npm, always going to have this error :

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-04T09_55_47_791Z-debug.log
```

I then tryed "npm install --no-package-lock", getting this error :

```
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path /usr/src/client/node_modules/.webpack-dev-server.DELETE/ssl
npm ERR! errno -16
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir '/usr/src/client/node_modules/.webpack-dev-server.DELETE/ssl'
```

When I try to run "rm -rf node_modules" on the container, I got the same kind of error :

```
rm: can't remove 'node_modules/.webpack-dev-server.DELETE/ssl': Resource busy
```

Here is the docker-compose part :

```
client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      target: api_platform_client_development
      cache_from:
        - ${CLIENT_IMAGE:-quay.io/api-platform/client}
    image: ${CLIENT_IMAGE:-quay.io/api-platform/client}
    tty: true # https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688
    environment:
      - API_PLATFORM_CLIENT_GENERATOR_ENTRYPOINT=http://api
      - API_PLATFORM_CLIENT_GENERATOR_OUTPUT=src
    depends_on:
      - dev-tls
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/client:rw,cached
      - dev-certs:/usr/src/client/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl:rw,nocopy
    ports:
      - target: 3000
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
```

And the associated Dockerfile :

```
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage
# https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#target


# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG NODE_VERSION=13
ARG NGINX_VERSION=1.17


# "development" stage
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_client_development

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

RUN yarn global add @api-platform/client-generator

RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
  python \
  make \
  build-base

# prevent the reinstallation of node modules at every changes in the source code
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN set -eux; \
  yarn install

COPY . ./

VOLUME /usr/src/client/node_modules

ENV HTTPS true

CMD ["yarn", "start"]


# "build" stage
# depends on the "development" stage above
FROM api_platform_client_development AS api_platform_client_build

ARG REACT_APP_API_ENTRYPOINT

RUN set -eux; \
  yarn build


# "nginx" stage
# depends on the "build" stage above
FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_client_nginx

COPY docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /usr/src/client/build

COPY --from=api_platform_client_build /usr/src/client/build ./
```

Is there a way to completely RESET (ie: clean install) only this service, without touching the others ? I know we can remove all volumes with options, but didn't find how to act only on one service. I have a database on another service that I don't want to loose. :/

Thanks !

Comment: You have a combination of volumes stacked up on top of your container that results in your Dockerfile basically completely being ignored.  Does deleting the `volumes:` from the `docker-compose.yml` file, and the `VOLUME` directive in the Dockerfile, improve things at all?  (And then you can `docker-compose build` in a clean environment.)

Comment: The only named volume that your `client` service is using  is `dev-certs`, which can be removed using `docker volume rm dev-certs` without touching any other volumes.

That said, why are you mounting this named volume to `node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl`, overriding the mounted volume above it? Assuming this named volume contains SSL certificates, wouldn't it be easier to configure `webpack-dev-server` to look for custom certificates in a different location of your choosing?

Comment: Well, I am quite new to Docker and to be honest, I simply kept the docker-compose.yml done by ApiPlatform itself
I don't really know why they used the binding, I'll try to find if I can change webpack configuration to use the volume without binding

Comment: Because you already mount the local `./client` folder, perhaps you can configure `webpack-dev-server` to looks for your SSL (dev) certificates in a folder such as `./client/.ssl`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616816/webpack4-webpack-dev-server-ssl-in-config-file) might help you do so.